# ViewPager setCurrentItem last fragment position

Tags: android, position, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a custom view with 5 tabs (like an action bar with tabs) and a ViewPager. When a tab is selected the container fragment is changed with the selected fragment (by tab).

Everything works fine, if I swipe between fragments or I'm selecting tabs in order or reverse.

(**Fragments swipe or selecting tabs**)

0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4

0 <- 1 <- 2 <- 3 <- 4

My problem is at first run, lets say that I'm on the first position (fragment 0) and I want to go to fragments 2, 3 or 4 by pressing the tab. For example, if I press the tab at position 4, it should change the container fragment:

> viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);

The fragment is not changed! I think it is because the Fragment is not created.

Comment: Do you got any error ?

Comment: No, it is not crashing.

Comment: But in my case, setting that method works as required.